# class method from instance in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron-task

I got a cron job in my project, this job execute a Model.

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
     def self.test
         number = getNumber(1)
     end

     def getNumber(i)
         value = 2 + i
         return value
     end
end
```

how can I access the function getNumber ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `self` keyword before the call to `getNumber(1)` in your `self.test` method? For e.g. `number = self.getNumber(1)`

Comment: And then try calling it with `Example.test`

Comment: `getNumber` looks stateless. Why isn't it a class method?

Comment: yes, I got this error when I try adding the self before the call. 
`undefined method `getnumber' for Example`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev   `class Test

  def getnumber
    return 2
  end

end`

I call Test.getnumber dont work

Comment: @volt: you didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your getNumber method (which should be `get_number`) is an instance method so you would need to call `Example.new.get_number(1)` however as mentioned by others it is stateless so could also be a class method so this would work:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.test
    number = get_number(1)
  end

  def self.get_number(i)
    value = 2 + i
    return value
  end
end
```

Comment: Or just `def self.get_number(i); 2 + i; end` :)

Answer (score 0):

Within `self.test` you are in the class (not in the instance). When you call `getNumber` Ruby will look for a class method. What you have above is an instance method. If you change your code from `def getNumber(i)` to `def self.getNumber(i)` it will do what you want.

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.test
    number = getNumber(1)
  end

  def self.getNumber(i)
    value = 2 + i
    return value
  end
end

puts Example.test
```

When run will output `3`.